# How to show results sending from one component to other component?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I have a filter component: ExtendedSearch component. And I have a list component that has to get the results from the extendedSearch component. And I have a service call that is used by the ExtendedSearch call.

Answer (score 1):

Try referring to this answer ([Angular 8: pass a data to a router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58391976/angular-8-pass-a-data-to-a-router/58450327#58450327)) which I gave to a similar question. It has 4 methods on how to handle this issue.

1. Parent to Child: Sharing Data via `Input()`
2. Child to Parent: Sharing Data via `ViewChild`
3. Child to Parent: Sharing Data via `Output()` and `EventEmitter`
4. Unrelated Components: Sharing Data with a Service (Recommended)

Hope this will help!

Good luck!