# Send data from one component to another within form

Tags: angular, typescript

How to send the data from one component to another? I have two components and I am using to selector to show the html in first component now I want to send the data entered in form to the first component.

***product component.html***

```
<form id="form" #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)">
  <label>
  <div class="field-heading">Name</div>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="product.name" name="productName" class=" theme-input" id="text" 
placeholder="Enter product name">
  </label>
  <product-variant> </product-variant>
</form>
```

***product component.ts***

```
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit{
 variant = new Variant();
 product= new Product();
 constructor() { }
 ngOnInit() {

 }
onSubmit(){
   console.log(this.product);
   console.log(this.variant);
}
```

***ProductVariant component.html***

```
<label>
  <div class="field-heading">Starting Inventory</div>
  <input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="variant.reorderLevel" name="reorder" class=" theme-input" id="text" 
placeholder=" Starting Inventory">
</label>
```

***ProductVariant component.ts***

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
templateUrl: 'product-variant.component.html',
selector: 'product-variant'  
 })
export class ProductVariant implements OnInit {
variant = new Variant();
// send data from this component to the product
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q9pxgj?embed=1&file=src/app/product-variant/product-variant.component.ts)**

product.component.html

> (onVariantChange)="variant = $event"

```
<form id="form" #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)">
    <label>
<div class="field-heading">Name</div>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="product.name" name="productName" class=" theme-input" id="text" 
placeholder="Enter product name">
</label>
    <product-variant (onVariantChange)="variant = $event"> </product-variant>
</form>


-----------------------------------------
product : {{product | json}}
variant : {{variant | json}}
```

product-variant.component.html

> (ngModelChange)="onChange()

```
<label>
  <div class="field-heading">Starting Inventory</div>
  <input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="variant.reorderLevel" name="reorder" class=" theme-input" id="text" 
placeholder=" Starting Inventory" (ngModelChange)="onChange()">
</label>
```

product-variant.component.ts

> `onChange() {
>       this.onVariantChange.emit(this.variant)
>     }`

```
  @Output() onVariantChange = new EventEmitter();



  onChange() {
    this.onVariantChange.emit(this.variant)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the problem is I am getting the output in the following format.
Variant {reorderLevel: "1"} Variant {reorderLevel: "12"} Variant {reorderLevel: "123"}
Is there any way to get the complete output in single object

Comment: Can you fork my demo and share it

Comment: Never mind there was a mistake in my code, you solution is working. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. Please upvote and accept the answer if this helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You Can Change Code Accordingly

**product component.html**

```
<form id="form" #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)">
 <label>
 <div class="field-heading">Name</div>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="product.name" name="productName" class=" theme-input" id="text" 
placeholder="Enter product name">
</label>
<product-variant (variant)=getVariantvalue($event)> </product-variant>
</form>
```

**product component.ts**

```
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit{
 variant = new Variant();
 product= new Product();
 constructor() { }
 ngOnInit() {

 }
onSubmit(){
   console.log(this.product);
   console.log(this.variant);
}
getVariantvalue($event){
  this.variant = $event
}
}
```

**ProductVariant component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild, EventEmitter, Output} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'product-variant.component.html',
  selector: 'product-variant'
})
export class ProductVariant implements OnInit {
  @Output()
  returnVariant: EventEmitter<Variant> = new EventEmitter();
  variant = new Variant();

// send data from this component to the product
  returnVariant() {
    returnVariant.emit(variant)
  }
}
```

Angular Guid [component-interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Hope this will helps ..!

**Update:**
You can find a detailed answer using this also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58450327/4593145

Comment: you are using a function called returnVariant(), where are you calling this function?

Comment: you can use it when veriant input change like  `<input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="variant" name="reorder" class=" theme-input" id="text" 
placeholder=" Starting Inventory" (ngModelChange)="returnVariant($event)"> `

Comment: Its working fine but the problem is lets say if I enter 123 in input field then the output is like this
Variant {reorderLevel: "1"}
Variant {reorderLevel: "12"}
Variant {reorderLevel: "123"}

Comment: If that the case u can implement onChange method in product variant component.ts like onChange() { this.returnVariant.emit(this.variant) }

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple approaches.

You can use services and dependency injection as described here:

https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services

And you can use Observables and especially "subject":
https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular

http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html